# Best way to send an async message to the parent viewmodel before closing?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm opening a dialog viewmodel from a "parent" viewmodel. When the dialog is closed, i want the parent viewmodel to refresh the updated fields.

INotifyPropertyChange is not usable, as android activities can be dismissed and recreated. At first i thought that it was not a problem: if the activity is recreated, the view is refreshed. So i tryed to open the dialog with the object instances owned by the parent view. But mvvmcross won't let you do that: viewmodel constructor parameters must be serializable and simple types. And that makes sense, as the memory used by these objects may be freed when the activity is destroyed.

IMvxMessenger seems the way to go. Publishing a Refresh message from the dialog before it closes. The parent subscribe to this message and refresh the properties accordingly.

But IMvxMessenger.Publish takes the sender object as a parameter. Will this leads to a memory leak ? Will this retain the viewmodel, which is closing, in memory ? Is that dangerous for app stability ?

Comment: My gut would be you are actually saving via some sort of service - I would send the message from there.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean by "opening a dialog viewmodel" - is this a genuine dialog (e.g. a `DialogFragment`) or is it a new `Activity`? Unfortunately here, this is an area where Android App/Activity lifecycle matters.

Comment: It is an Activity with a dialog theme.

Comment: I know that for fragments there is no problem. The parent activity can not be recycled. For messages, all objects stored in a message are retained in memory until the message is delivered. Is this right ? It should :) If yes, there is no problem and the question is answered.

Comment: No - in `MvxMessenger` messages are not stored for future delivery. If you want to implement a "drop box service" which caches specific message types, then you can do this yourself easily enough.

Comment: Does this mean that if a viewmodel publish a message before closing itself, the "parent" activity (which may be recreated by android, and subscribes to this message in its oncreate) won't receive the message ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Actions which will be invoked in the caller.

```
public class DialogMessage
    : MvxMessage
{
    public DialogMessage(object sender) : base(sender)
    {
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public Style Buttons { get; set; }

    public Action OkAction { get; set; }
    public Action CancelAction { get; set; }
    public Action YesAction { get; set; }
    public Action NoAction { get; set; }

    public enum Style
    {
        Ok,
        YesNo
    }
}
```

Comment: This should not work, as the calling activity may be destroyed/recreated by Android. The only achievement of this is your child viewmodel preventing the parent activity instance from being released from memory.

Comment: This does work. But you are right, the calling activity may be destroyed. Nonetheless, from practical stand point, your dialog is most likely very simple activity which likely won't cause the caller to be pushed out of the memory. I tested this on a number of devices and it yet to let me down.

Answer (score 1):

> IMvxMessenger seems the way to go. Publishing a Refresh message from
>   the dialog before it closes. The parent subscribe to this message and
>   refresh the properties accordingly.

Yes this is the way to go, IMO.

> But IMvxMessenger.Publish takes the sender object as a parameter. Will
>   this leads to a memory leak? Will this retain the viewmodel, which is
>   closing, in memory ? Is that dangerous for app stability ?

I don't think so, **unless** you use that sender reference from the Subscriber's event handler to the message. For example, let's say that on your subscriber you have:

```
_newProductToken = _messenger.Subscribe<NewProductMessage>( OnNewProductMessage, MvxReference.Strong );
```

And your message class looks like this:

```
class NewProductMessage : MvxMessage
{
    public NewProductMessage( object p_sender, string p_code, string p_description )
       : base(p_sender)
    {
        Code = p_code;
        Description = p_sescription;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And your Subscriber's event handler to the message looks like:

```
private void OnNewProductMessage( NewProductMessage p_Product )
{
   // Obviously this might cause an exception if the sender is removed by the time this line is exec'd
   var myvar = p_Product.sender; 

  // But you could use the other properties of your message class of course...
   ProductCode = p_Product.Code;
   Description = p_Product.Description;
}
```

Therefore, it all depends how the MvxMessage class uses the sender object passed to it-via `base(p_sender)`. You really need to examine the source code for the Messenger Plugin, which you can find here, I believe:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/3.0.14/Plugins/Cirrious/Messenger/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger

HTH,
Pap